# How can I restore my httpd.conf on my Mac? (OSX 10.12)

Tags: php, macos, apache, httpd.conf

I was trying to enable PHP on my Mac, so I just simply followed the steps shown in this website:
https://jason.pureconcepts.net/2015/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-el-capitan/

However, when I came to the step below:

```
vi httpd.conf
```

I can see the `http.conf` file, but somehow something went wrong, and I really had no idea. I think I've probably accidentally deleted the `httpd.conf` file?

Now when I use the same command:

```
vi httpd.conf
```

Here's what I see:

[image: they are all ~]

How can I restore this file? httpd.conf?

Comment: You tell us where you backed it up to!! And we will tell you how to restore it!!!!

Comment: Basically this mean you somehow (re)moved the file and you're getting an empty/new file now. Either you re-download the example version, not sure how it looks for the Mac Apache, or revert the remove part.
I do see "cp httpd.conf httpd.conf.bak" this in the article, so maybe you still have a backup in the same directory?

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/243497/can-any-one-upload-their-httpd-conf-file-for-mac

Comment: Hi there, actually I just somehow found my backup file, and I have restored it back!